# Проверка правильности ввода значения

Tags: c++, c

Необходимо проверить правильность ввода числа на входе (пример: 8 -правильно, а - ошибка). Знаю, что для c++ можно сделать так:

```
int n;
if (cin.good()){
...
}
```

А как сделать то же самое, только не для cin, а для scanf. Пробовал scanf.good(), но не работает

Answer (score 1):

У [`scanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) возвращаемое значение говорит о количестве успешно прочитанных аргументов. На него и опирайтесь.

`scanf` это функция, не надо пытаться бездумно дописывать `.good()`, там где оно не имеет никакого смысла. В первую очередь - смотрите документацию.

Answer (score 1):

[`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) возвращает количество верно считанных значений. Т.е. если у вас `scanf("%d",&n)` вернет не 1 - значит, ничего не считано... Если 0 - то скорее всего потому что формат не подходит, если `EOF` - то проблемы с чтением, вообще не считан ни один символ.